# json print required data with ng-repat

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

i am new to coding and i am starting with angular js....

i have a json like below

```
$scope.data={
    "items":
        {
            "yamaha":
                {
                   "title":"R15",
                   "description":"sports mode",
                   "speed":"180kmph"
                },
            "Tvs":
                {
                   "title":"apache",
                   "description":"sports mode",
                   "speed":"150kmph"
                }
        }
};
```

now my requirement is to show each value one after other in html.....

**Note**
As i said i am new,i have googled this and found some info like ng-repeat but i didnt understand how to use this in while implementing.

thanks for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-repeat will iterate over the data in the given array....here i used key,vakue concept to print object keys and values

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.items">

    <div><h2>{{k}}</h2>
        <p>{{ v.title }}</p>
        <p>{{v.description }}</p>
        <p>{{v.speed }}</p>
    </div>


</div>
</body>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data={
        "items":
            {
                "yamaha":
                    {
                       "title":"R15",
                       "description":"sports mode",
                       "speed":"180kmph"
                    },
                "Tvs":
                    {
                       "title":"apache",
                       "description":"sports mode",
                       "speed":"150kmph"
                    }
            }
    };
  
  
});
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks ya this is what i am expecting and you cleared me that how to print brand names at once